# Cannot use REST comments in Swagger

Tags: rest, swagger, api-doc

I have downloaded swagger ui and experimenting it locally. It works fine in scenarios like "path", "body" , and "query" .  But  most of my use cases use rest comments.

i.e  /resourcePath/;tags
URI to retrieve the tags of a specific resource.

When I try this the the UI gets jumbled when adding the semi colon and malformed the sorted UI and cannot go beyond this.

So is this a known  limitation ? Is there a workaround to accomplish this target ?
Appreciate any input to this..

Comment: Hi Thanks for pointing that out. Now its done. Infact I have missed to accept the answers for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger is expecting you to specify `path` params in curly-brackets like `{tags}` and query params as comma-delimited, such as `id=1,2,3,4`.  Some frameworks use semi-colons as delimiters but swagger likes commas.

Can you describe more what you're looking to do, with a more concrete example?  Per design, comments on the api belong in the `description` and `notes` fields for operations, please see [swagger-core wiki](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki) for details.

The [Swagger codegen](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen) project has a validator which can be used to verify that your spec is properly formatted.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. Let me give you a simple example.  i.e /local/node1;rating:4.5  which gives the rating of 4.5 to the node at /local/node1.  For more information please refer [1]
[1] - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-23 . 
So the issue is when we do so, the swagger UI gets jumbled and can't proceed. Is there a way for us to accomplish this with swagger? Appreciate any help.